# Apache Kafka SimpleConsumer Example

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm following the Kafka documentation on this page and trying to get the SimpleConsumer up and running:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example

When I tried running it against Java 1.7, Scala 2.11 and with Kafka 0.9.0.0, I could not compile the file anymore:

```
[error] /Users/jothi/Sandbox/jaguar/spark-kafka-consumer/src/main/java/com/eon/vpp/SimpleExample.java:175: error: host has private access in Broker
[error]                 m_replicaBrokers.add(replica.host());
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I managed to get this work. I changed my Kafka version to 0.8.0!

How do I make use of this Consumer? I do the following currently:

```
joe$ java -cp spark-kafka-consumer-0.1.0-SNAPAHOT.jar com.eon.vpp.SimpleMetricsConsumer 10000 test_topic 1 9092
```

The program expects 5 arguments:

```
1. Maximum number of messages to read (so we don’t loop forever)
2. Topic to read from
3. Partition to read from
4. One broker to use for Metadata lookup
5. Port the brokers listen on
```

What should I be using for arguments 4 and 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:
**4.** Any broker hostname or IP address
**5.** 9092 is the default port specified in the configuration, so that should be fine

BTW, just in case you have a single partition, you know that partition IDs start from 0?

Answer (score 0):

You will have these information available in configuration file located at: `

```
${kafka-folder}/config/server.properties
```

with properties name as below:

- port (default is 9092 but you can define your own as well)
- host.name (default is localhost, you can define your broker IP/hostname)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kafka got very good documentation read through [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction), you can find information about consumer, subscriber also various configurations, partitions and much more.